# python: writing CSV files with sequence numbering

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i am trying to read a csv file & write the content based on first 2 columns inside that, with a sequence number. All this is working fine.. But my challenge is to append the files instead of writing new files for each row..

`test.csv`

```
2002,2402,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2002,2002,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
2402,2402,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
2002,2402,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
3333,2402,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
3333,3333,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
```

output files:

```
2002_200418_000000001.csv
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2002_200418_000000002.csv
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
2002_200418_000000003.csv
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
2402_200418_000000001.csv
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2402_200418_000000002.csv
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
2402_200418_000000003.csv
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
2402_200418_000000004.csv
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
3333_200418_000000001.csv
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
3333_200418_000000002.csv
6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
```

`python code:`

```
import os, csv, datetime
from itertools import cycle

seq = {'2002': cycle(range(1,999)),'2402': cycle(range(1,999)),'3333': cycle(range(1,999))}

def SequenceNum(f):
    return f'{next(seq[f])}'.zfill(9)

def filegenerate(X):
    with open(X) as csvfile:
        timestamp = '_' + '{:%y%m%d%H%M%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()) + '_'
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar="'")
        for cdr in reader:
            if cdr[0] == '' and cdr[1] == '':
                pass
            elif cdr[0] == cdr[1]:
                with open(cdr[0] + timestamp + SequenceNum(cdr[0]) + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar="'")
                    writer.writerow(cdr[2:])
                    f.close()
            elif cdr[0] != cdr[1] and cdr[1] != '' and cdr[0] != '':
                with open(cdr[0] + timestamp + SequenceNum(cdr[0]) + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar="'")
                    writer.writerow(cdr[2:])
                    f.close()
                with open(cdr[1] + timestamp + SequenceNum(cdr[1]) + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar="'")
                    writer.writerow(cdr[2:])
                    f.close()
            elif cdr[1] != '' and cdr[0] == '':
                with open(cdr[1] + timestamp + SequenceNum(cdr[1]) + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar="'")
                    writer.writerow(cdr[2:])
                    f.close()
            elif cdr[0] != '' and cdr[1] == '':
                with open(cdr[0] + timestamp + SequenceNum(cdr[0]) + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar="'")
                    writer.writerow(cdr[2:])
                    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filegenerate('test.csv')
```

From the above output, 2002 file is generated multiple times based on row count, i want to append rows to corresponding file.. please help to improve my code.

`expected output:`

```
2002_200418_000000001.csv
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4

2402_200418_000000001.csv
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5

3333_200418_000000001.csv
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
```

i think this issue is because of seq numbering being assigned while writing file, may be i can append all rows into 2002..etc files and later rename them with seq number.. BUT IS THERE ANY BETTER APPROACH??

for questions raised why seq is required, when each file is ended with 000000001, its because when i iterate over multiple .csv files, seq numbering will be assigned & incremented further.

```
example:
test1.csv
test2.csv
test3.csv

output:
2002_200418_000000001.csv
2402_200418_000000001.csv
3333_200418_000000001.csv

2002_200418_000000002.csv
2402_200418_000000002.csv
3333_200418_000000002.csv

2002_200418_000000003.csv
2402_200418_000000003.csv
3333_200418_000000003.csv
```

my idea, seq number should be assigned with respect each .csv but not with respect to each row of the csv files.
Please help...

thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the logic behind your sequence numbers?

Comment: In the expected output all the files end with the same sequence number `000000001`??

Comment: Seq numbering logic is that when column1 is found, is writing the file with that name (2002 for example), SequenceNum function will assign different numbering for that number itself..

Comment: 2002,2402, 3333 are defined under dict seq, and sequenceNum function will assign different seq number each of these numbers.

Comment: But is that sequence number really necessary if files are appended? Don't you end up with a single file for each of the numbers 2002, 2402, 3333?

Comment: Or do you want to have files like:
2002_...._00000001.csv / 
2402_...._00000002.csv / 
3333_...._00000003.csv

Comment: But in your expected output all the files are using the same seq numbers. Still not clear.

Comment: @stefan, Shubham, thanks for response.. in this example each output file will be generated with 00000001 as seq number, but my idea is to use this to iterate multiple csv files, so that seq number will be incremented further..

Comment: Sorry, if i am not clear about the requirement., i have updated my question at last, explaining seq number format if i iterate over multiple test csv files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approach where the future file contents are collected in a dictionary before they are written to disk. For each future file, an entry is made in the dictionary that contains a set with the lines of the file. I've chosen a set because I assumed that if you encounter the same content in the columns >= 3 that you only want to have it written once in the output. You could replace the set with a list, if that is not the case.

```
import os, csv, datetime
from itertools import cycle

seq = { '2002': cycle(range(1,999)),
        '2402': cycle(range(1,999)),
        '3333': cycle(range(1,999)) }

def SequenceNum(f):
    return f'{next(seq[f])}'.zfill(9)

def filegenerate(filePath: str) -> None:
    with open(filePath, 'r') as csvFile:
        rows = [row for row in csv.reader(csvFile, quotechar="'")]

    fileContents = dict()
    for row in rows:
        fileContents.setdefault(row[0], set()).add(','.join(row[2:]) + '\n')
        fileContents.setdefault(row[1], set()).add(','.join(row[2:]) + '\n')

    timestamp = '_' + '{:%y%m%d%H%M%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()) + '_'
    for key in fileContents:
        lines = list(fileContents[key])
        lines.sort()
        with open(str(key) + timestamp + SequenceNum(key) + '.csv', 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filegenerate('test.csv')
```

This code produces the following files with your provided `test.csv`:

`2002_200418103658_000000001.csv`

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
```

`2402_200418103658_000000001.csv`

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
```

`3333_200418103658_000000001.csv`

```
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
```

Comment: perfect.. thanks a lot Stefan.. this is my exact requirement.

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, Use:

```
def SequenceNum(seq):
    return f'{seq}'.zfill(9)

def write_file(n, data, seq):
    filename = n + '_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d") + '_' + SequenceNum(seq) + '.csv'
    with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar="'")
        writer.writerow(data)

def read_files():
    files = ["test1.csv", "test2.csv", "test3.csv"]

    for idx, filename in enumerate(files, 1): # process each file one by one
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for line in reader:
                n1, n2, *data = line
                write_file(n1, data, idx)
                if n1 != n2:
                    write_file(n2, data, idx)
```

Calling the function:

```
read_files()
```

This creates the following files:

```
2002_200418_000000001.csv
2402_200418_000000001.csv
3333_200418_000000001.csv

2002_200418_000000002.csv
2402_200418_000000002.csv
3333_200418_000000002.csv

2002_200418_000000003.csv
2402_200418_000000003.csv
3333_200418_000000003.csv
```